# Flutter launcher - How to update app list when I uninstall an app?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, launcher

Hi everyone I'm really new to flutter and programming. I'm trying to create an android app launcher with flutter.

I looked everywhere but I can't find an answer to my problem.

I'm using the package: **device_apps**

So to retrieve the app list I'm using

```
List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();
```

How can I update my listview when I install/uninstall an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications()` returns a `List<Application>` which we can use to draw our `ListView`:

```
Widget _buildListView() {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Application app = _apps[index];
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              onTap: () => DeviceApps.openApp(app.packageName),
              title: Text('${app.appName} (${app.packageName})'),
            ),
            Divider()
          ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: _apps.length);
}
```

We could load the installed applications immediately after initializing the state by overriding the `initState` method of a `StatefulWidget`:

```
List<Application> _apps = [];

@override 
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _loadApps();
}

Future<void> _loadApps() async {
  List<Application> applications = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();
  setState(() => _apps = applications);
}

Widget _buildListView() {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Application app = _apps[index];
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              onTap: () => DeviceApps.openApp(app.packageName),
              title: Text('${app.appName} (${app.packageName})'),
            ),
            Divider()
          ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: _apps.length);
}
```

In this way, we could also easily use a `GestureDetector` to reload the installed applications:

```
Widget _buildRefreshButton() {
   return GesetureDetector(
      onTap: () async { await _loadApps(); }
      child: Text("Reload apps")
   );
}
```

---

The best solution would be to get notified whenever an app is uninstalled/installed, but unfortunately, this function is not yet supported by the package.

An hacky workaround would be to poll the `_loadApps()` above by the means of a `Timer.periodic`, however, it is not recommended for performance and UX reasons.